# WPF и ASP.NET только видео уроки на русском для C#

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net

Посоветуйте видео уроки по WPF и ASP.NET (С#) на русском. Интересует только видео уроки, прошу учесть всех кто ответит. Мнения что лучше а, что нет прошу не озвучивать *Сайто-постояльцы ругаются*. **Убедительная просьба писать исключительно по теме**.

Comment: С русскоязычными видео-курсами на самом деле бяда. Что-то чтоб хоть как-то было бы сопоставимо по уровню с англ. курсами `Pluralsight`или `Lynda` и проч. очень тяжело найти. Пожалуй, [ITVDN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3d3dRAEo70&list=PLvItDmb0sZw95wv4PCFipJch_mspptRFS) еще более-менее качественные курсы.

Comment: Хотите хоть немного разбираться — читайте книги.

Comment: Поиск литературы и других источников знаний вне выделенных для этого вопросов — оффтопик.

Comment: @VladD Я думаю любой кто хоть немного хочет заниматься программированием для начала ищет литературу по интересующему его вопросу а,потом уже видео! Это очевидно! И книги это конечно неоспоримо лучший вариант но только если вы студент и у вас много времени и преподаватель который может вам всё объяснить! В остальных случаях приходиться выслушивать вот такие комментарии как у вас, не по теме и абсолютно не помогающие!

Comment: "Сайтопостояльцы ругаются." - ну дык здесь есть правила и по ним поиск литературы и всяких видеокурсов - оффтопик.

Comment: @Андрей NOP Что такое ОФФТОПИК? И как же мне задать вопрос? Были же полезные ответы. Взяли закрыли? Почему?

Comment: Если что-то не понятно по правилам ресурса - задайте вопрос на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень хорошие курсы от ITVDN. Они платные, но в интернете можете найти их RIP'аные версии.

[Оф. сайт.](https://itvdn.com/ru/catalog)

Comment: Вот нашёл отличный курс по ASP.NET MVC 3  вот ссылка на официальный сайт [https://alekseev74.ru/courses/aspnetmvc] курс немного староват, за то объясняет на примерах и довольно подробно! А, главное понятно! Его канал [https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDM5jufVw9yLOUPcFLG8Idw] на Yuotube